# How to remove the file extension in a zsh completion?

Tags: string, zsh, file-extension, tab-completion

I want to adjust zsh so that I can tab complete:

```
myprog <tab>
```

using all `*.foo` files in `~/somedir`, but have it so that it displays them *without* the `.foo` extension.

Is there any way to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
#compdef myprog
typeset -A opt_args
local context state line
local -a mydirs
mydirs="(. ~/somedir)"

_arguments -s -S \
    "*:name:->foos" \
    && return 0

case $state in
    (foos)
        _files -W ${mydirs} -g '*.foo(:r)' && return 0
    ;;
esac

return 1
```

However, this displays double the output for every file (that is, each `.foo` file is listed with and without its extension). Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set the `file-patterns` style, probably using `'%p:globbed-files'`.

Comment: Would you mind extending upon this answer a bit? I'm not entirely familiar with zsh's completion syntax, and am having trouble deducing where to start with this.

Comment: Nvm, got it: `zstyle ':completion:*' file-patterns '%p:globbed-files:'` belongs in my .zshrc. Thanks!